# His Health Pick Up

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

According to dictionary, one definition for a intransitive use of the phrase "*pick up*" is to improve.  So, could I write these?

> 1. The situation finally ***picked up***.
> 2. His health finally ***picked up***.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is a bit tricky. It's hard to tell what about the situation is picking up; *pick up* can also mean improve in speed or grow stronger:

> The winds have really **picked up** out there.

In this case, you're probably better off just sticking to "improved."

As for your second sentence, it's perfectly acceptable, though I do think you're more likely to see "improved" when talking about health.